# Linking to show in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

okay so I have this controller (courses_controller.rb) with def show as follows :

```
def show
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
end
```

I want to link to it like so:

```
<%= link_to "Back", :controller => "courses", :action => "show", course => @lesson.course_id %>
```

lesson.rb does have a course_id by the way. it's the last segment (course => @lesson.course_id)
that is giving me issues. the latter part of the statement works, its the "course" part that I cant get right. I've also tried @course. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure that you have setup course-lesson relationship in your models? In `RAILS_APP/app/models/lesson.rb`, you'll need

```
Class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
end
```

And in `RAILS_APP/app/models/course.rb`, you should have

```
Class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lessons
end
```

Then, in your views, you can just put,

```
<%= link_to "Back", @lessson.course %>
```

That should be all.

Answer (score 3):

Easy!

```
<%= link_to "Back", course_path(@lesson) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
<%= link_to "Back", :controller => "courses", :action => "show", :id => @lesson.course_id %>
```

instead of "course" use "id", It will work fine.